# module:status in alphabetical order?

Tags: magento-2.1, cli

I'm just wondering if anybody has figured out how to list the output of:

```
magento module:status
```

in alphabetical order?  Right now it seems to output them in some random order that doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order the modules appear in `app/etc/config.php` and the `module:status` output is determined by the [Component Load Order](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html), which modifies which components load before others based on the `<sequence>` tag in each module's `etc/module.xml` config file.

For instance, the `Magento_AdvancedRule` module needs the `Magento_Rule` to load first, so it appears after `Magento_Rule` in the list even though the name is alphabetically before it.

```
<config>
    <module name="Magento_AdvancedRule" setup_version="2.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Rule"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

If you want to sort the output another way, it seem's like you have two options:

1. `$ bin/magento module:status | sort`
2. Write a new Magento CLI command that extends `module:status` and buffers the output, sorting it before outputting.

Comment: Ahh interesting.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: well, I'm assuming by your post that due to where it gets its order from, it cannot be organized in any other way.

Comment: I just added two options I thought of to sort the output, either by creating a new command, or piping the output to the `sort` command.

Comment: yeah, not sure why I never thought of piping sort to the output. ><  Thanks for that info.  I've added a shortcut alias to my .bashrc file.